Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] on the Node js, typeorm and mysql project
I am getting an error on the Node JS, typeorm and mysql project when trying to connect to mysql.
I am new in Node js and mysql. Please help me to fix this issue.
I have shared code of index.ts file, and hosts file
Error is
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1606:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}

index.ts file code is below
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from "express";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

const app: Express = express();
dotenv.config();

// Create Database Connection
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    username: "root",
    password: "",
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DB,
    synchronize: true,
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send('Express + TypeScript Server!')
});


AppDataSource.initialize().then(() => {
    app.listen(port);
    console.log('Data Source has been initialized!')
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(
        'Error during Data Source initialization - ',
        err,
    );
});

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc file is
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.1.38 host.docker.internal
192.168.1.38 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section



Is your MySQL Server running?
